# PyQt compiled with PyInstaller looks strange (old) - macOS

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I've written a small PyQt script that does a quiz with radio buttons and a submit button (I can post the code if you want). When I run it as a script, the buttons and checkbox have a modern look and feel and look exactly like a normal Qt app. However, when I compile it with PyInstaller, it results in some ancient-looking look and feel which seems like it belongs in XP.

Here is a screenshot comparing the two (compiled on the right):
[image: Running as a script on the left, compiled on the right]

My PyInstaller compile code is `pyinstaller quiz.py --onefile --windowed --add-data questions.csv:.`

Regardless of whether it is run in windowed or not, or in onefile mode or not, I get this ancient look and feel.

Comment: Could you try `pyinstaller -y -F --distpath="." --noconsole quiz.py --add-data questions.csv:.`

Comment: I think --noconsole or --windowed is ignored on MAcOs

Comment: Still the same issue with these options, @ymmx. To my knowledge `--noconsole` isn't ignored on macOS as it does launch without a console window.

Comment: Are you sure you launch the pyinstaller in the same python folder that you excecute the non compiled code?

Comment: If you put the code I could test it on my Window see if that also happend

Comment: @ymmx just tested it and the issue also happens on windows; going back to an older version of pyqt5 (5.9.2) does fix the issue

Answer (score 4):

The newest version of pyqt5 isn't compatible with pyinstaller; use the older version of pyqt5.

To re-install it through pip:

`pip3 install pyqt5==5.9.2`

or

`pip3 install https://pypi.python.org/packages/5e/41/93bf8f289b476bc5d8cece7948a166cbcea761f5b1262e5fdd7076a5e02a/PyQt5-5.9.2-5.9.3-cp35.cp36.cp37-abi3-macosx_10_6_intel.whl#md5=926b3841d74d178171a2bbc0946fe2a4`

You're welcome!

Comment: small question; where did you get the "isn't compatible with pyinstaller" part ? official statement or experience ?

Comment: @AlexGarcia can't really remember I saw someone say it in stack overflow somewhere I think